# modx revo set user login for 1 week

Tags: session-cookies, modx-revolution

I am facing a problem to remember user login in modx revolution. I am using login extra with MODX Revolution 2.2.8-pl (traditional). i am trying to set user login for a week.

I have set system setting

```
session_cookie_lifetime = 1209600
session_gc_maxlifetime = 1209600
```

When i am loging i got below array in `$scriptProperties`

```
Array
(
    [actionKey] => service
    [contexts] => web,Danish,German,Swedish,Serbian,Italian,French,Russian,Spanish
    [errTpl] => lgnErrTpl
    [errTplType] => modChunk
    [loginKey] => login
    [loginMsg] => 
    [loginResourceId] => 1
    [loginResourceParams] => 
    [loginTpl] => tplLogin
    [logoutKey] => logout
    [logoutMsg] => 
    [logoutResourceId] => 0
    [logoutResourceParams] => 
    [logoutTpl] => lgnLogoutTpl
    [postHooks] => 
    [preHooks] => 
    [recaptchaTheme] => clean
    [redirectToOnFailedAuth] => 
    [redirectToPrior] => 
    [rememberMeKey] => rememberme
    [toPlaceholder] => 
    [tplType] => modChunk
)
```

if i login with check remember me option and i restart my computer it is showing me that i am log out!.  if i restart my browser it showing me login but if i restart my computer it showing me log out!

**Update**
I have printed cookie and it showing that PHPSESSID is set but it showing me that i am logout.

Is there anything that i need to set or is there anything that i have missed?

Any help will be highly appreciated .

Thanks,
Awlad

Answer (score 2):

Just change `session_cookie_lifetime` in system settings [image] http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/administering-your-site/settings/system-settings/session_cookie_lifetime

Comment: I already did that. i have updated my question. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: i was forgot to add this in my question. +1 for mention this :)